# Error when estimating a spatial panel model with splm::sp

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, plm

I am trying to estimate a spatial panel model with spml. The data (`bp_sf_subset`) nests years (2013-2019) within 690 block groups and has no missing values. I used the following code to obtain the weights list object:

```
nb2 <- poly2nb(bp_sf_subset, queen=TRUE)
#assign weights to each neighboring polygon
lw2 <- nb2listw(nb2, style="W", zero.policy=TRUE)
W <- listw2U(lw2)
```

Then, I estimate the following model:

```
# Estimate spatial panel data model
model <- spml(formula = viol_index_crime_rate_rep ~ 
                        ice_index + 
                        unemployment_rate_pop + 
                        poverty_rate_hh,
               data = bp_sf_subset,
               index = c("block_group","year"),
               model = "within",
               lag=TRUE,
               spatial.error = "b",
               effect = "twoways",
               listw = W)
```

When I do so, I get the following error: *Error in lag.listw(listw, u, zero.policy = zero.policy) : object lengths differ*

I've seen posts reporting similar problems and have tried all of the suggested solutions. Unfortunately, none have worked in my case. One of the posts suggested that the order of the index variables matters, so I made sure that the spatial index (block_group) precedes the time variable (year). I also changed the class of my data to "data.frame" and tried manipulating certain parameters of the model. For example, I set the index to "NULL" as one user had suggested on a previous post.